# Hide web page elements in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an android application that shows a page through a webview. But the web page has many elements that I don't want to show and that is why I hide them as follows:

```
  webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
               view.loadUrl ("javascript:(function() { "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-header-wrap td-header-style-1 ')[0].style.display='none'; "+ "document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[1].style.display='none';  "+"document.getElementsById('td_uid_1_5ff8cc46439eb ')[0].style.display='none'; "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='none';  "+"document.getElementsByClassName('tdm-mobile-full')[0].style.display='none'; "+"document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='none'; "+"} )()");

  }
```

Is it possible u**sing a javascript function to indicate only what should be shown** and **instead of indicating what to hide**?

Can I hide the complete body and only show one div element? I tried it but it does not work.

```
   view.loadUrl ("javascript:(function() { "+"document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.display='none'; "+ "document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='block';"+"} )()");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hide the `body` class and then show the class you want.

```java
view.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var p=document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0];p.style.visibility='hidden';p.style.width=0;p.style.height=0;p.style.padding=0;p.style.margin=0;document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index')[0].style.visibility='visible';)();");
```

Here is the JavaScript formatted:

```js
(function() {
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0]; 
    p.style.visibility='hidden';
    p.style.width=0;
    p.style.height=0;
    p.style.padding=0;
    p.style.margin=0;
    document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index')[0].style.visibility='visible';
)();
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not hide the body. It hide the body if I use this (but it does not show the div element):    view.loadUrl ("javascript:(function() { "+"document.getElementsByClassName('body')[0].style.display='none'; "+ "document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index ')[0].style.display='block';"+"} )()");

Comment: Do you need the body element to be fully unseen? If so is the style by the tag or by a class?

Comment: Depending on you answer this may work. `var shown = document.getElementsByClassName('td-fix-index')[0].outerHTML;
var hidden =  document.getElementsByClassName("body")[0];
hidden.outerHTML = shown;
hidden.setAttribute("class", "different");`